# how to destroy a weld joint

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I have searched extensively and haven't been able to find any guidelines or posts on destroying a weldJoint. How do I destroy the weldJoint between bodyA and bodyB? I created my weldJoint in the following way.

```
    weldJointDef.Initialize(bodyA, bodyB, bodyA->GetWorldCenter());
    weldJointDef.collideConnected = false;
    weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*) world->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
world->DestroyJoint( weldJoint );
```

Comment: we have to destroy joints Before Destroying body ??

Comment: Destroying a body will also destroy any joints that are attached to the body.